# Connected index category and limit of constant functor

Tags: category-theory

This is question 8 from chapter 4 section 2 of MacLane's *Category for the Working Mathematician*:

> If the category J is connected, prove for any $c \in C$ that $Lim \triangle c \cong c$ and $Colim \triangle c \cong c$, where $\triangle c: J \rightarrow C$ is the constant functor.

I'm not sure what the connectedness of J means to the mapping $\triangle c$, since any morphism in J is mapped to the identity $1_c$ in C. The lack of intuition is what's bothering me the most. MacLane does not offer much on connectedness beyond its definition. Can anyone explain to me what the general idea here is?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when $\mathcal{J}$ is not connected? For instance, what if $\mathcal{J}$ is two points?

Comment: @ZhenLin If $J$ is two points and no morphism between them, then if I understand correctly, the Lim and Colim cannot exist since there is no cone or cocone?

Comment: That's not correct. You should go reread the definition of limit and colimit.

Comment: @ZhenLin I think I am misunderstanding something very fundamental. Could you hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As I said, your assertion is not correct. The limit/colimit can exist. This computes the product/coproduct of two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get intuition by a counterexample, as ZhenLin suggested, let $\mathcal J$ be the discrete category of $2$ points. Then we get
$$\overset{\leftarrow}\lim\,\Delta c\ =\ c\times c\quad \text{ and }\quad \overset{\to}\lim\,\Delta c\ =\ c+c\,,$$
where $+$ denotes *coproduct* here. 
(Already in $\mathcal{Set}$ we have neither $A\times A\cong A$ nor $A+A\cong A$ for sets $A$ with cardinalty $\ge2$.)

Generally, a cone $\gamma$ from $c$ to a diagram (i.e. functor) $\ D:\mathcal J\to \mathcal C\ $ is a collection of morphisms $\gamma_j:c\to Dj$ (with $j\in Ob\,\mathcal J$) that makes all arising triangles commute, i.e. making $\ Df\circ\gamma_j=\gamma_{j_1}\ $ for all arrows $f:j\to j_1$ in $\mathcal J$.

In case $\mathcal J$ is discrete, this latter condition is vacuous, so any collection of morphisms $(\gamma_j:c\to Dj)_{j\in Ob\mathcal J}$ is a cone from $c$ to $D$, so by [co-]limit of $D$ we get back exactly the notion of [co-]product of objects $(Dj)_{j\in Ob\mathcal C}$.

The limit cone of a diagram $D$ might be visualized as the '*rightmost*' cone among all cones to $D$. (Precisely: each cone from $c$ to $D$ factors through uniquely the limit cone, so we get one-to-one correspondence between cones $c\leadsto D$ and morphisms $c\to\displaystyle\overset\leftarrow\lim D\ $ of $\,\mathcal C$).

---

So, back to the exercise, if $\mathcal J$ is connected, then what are the cones to the constant diagram $\Delta c$?

Comment: I am trying to visualize it: If $J$ is connected, are the cones to the constant diagram $\triangle c$ simply any collection of morphisms that are the same (so that the triangle made up by $1_c$ and 2 of these morphisms commute)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because of the condition that '*all arising triangles commute*'. (If otherwise $J$ is discrete, no such triangle arise at all.)